# Elastic search sorting issue with tokenizer

Tags: elasticsearch, kendo-grid

I am using KendoGrid and data source is from elastic search. When I sort by name the elastic search is providing me few unexpected results. After analyzing I observed that if I sort by any order ascending/descending, elastic search is splitting the string into words and within these words it is looking for the word which begins with lower/higher value respectively. For example.

```
Again Test for Hard bounce check
Campaign Sender Test
Test SMTP 2
Test SMTP 1
Test Campaign34
Test Campaign345
Campaign Test mergervars
Link test
Failed Test
```

The first item in the above list "Again Test for Hard bounce check" has been split into 5 words and since "Test" begins with T it shows up first in the list.

But, I do not want to sort this way. I want to sort from the beginning of the string. How do i do that.

I assume i have to handle it through the tokenizer but not sure how to do it. Please help.

Answer (score 1):

The sort happens on inverse inverse index , better knows as fielddata cache. The data that comes here is after tokenizing.
If you want to presrve the search feature and sort on that field too , then i highly recommended to use [multi fields](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/_multi_fields.html)

```
"title": {
    "type": "string",
    "fields": {
        "sort":   { "type": "string", "index": "not_analyzed" }
    }
}
```

Now we have two field internally for title field.
The title field and the title.sort.
Use the title.sort field as it has the exact string.